# Jquery .wrapAll confuses order of elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following elements's:

```
<span class="skilltext">HTML</span>
<span class="skilltextnumber">60%</span>
<span class="skilltext">CSS</span>
<span class="skilltextnumber">30%</span>
```

I then execue the following line of jquery in a .each function:

```
        $( this ).find( ".skilltextnumber, .skilltext" ).wrapAll( "<div class='skill-wrapper'></div>");
```

This works quie nice. However the order of the elements is now different.

```
<span class="skilltext">HTML</span>
<span class="skilltext">CSS</span>
<span class="skilltextnumber">60%</span>
<span class="skilltextnumber">30%</span>
```

How can i prevent jquery from messing up the order of my elements?

Comment: Can’t reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/517o3z9g/ (It seems to remove the whitespace between elements though.)

Comment: jQuery version used? - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/517o3z9g/1/

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$( this ).find( ".skilltextnumber, .skilltext" ).wrapAll( "<div class='skill-wrapper'></div>");
```

use

```
$( this ).find( "span" ).wrapAll( "<div class='skill-wrapper'></div>");
```

Comment: I have other span elements in the same div and only want to wrap those specific spans. Managed to fix it by using the selector span:not(.otherclass).